# ASP.NET MVC5 -I followed the Instructions and i constantly get Type 'ASP._Page_index_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am brand new to ASP.NET - and was following some tutorials. below are the screen shots that show what i have done exactly as recommended and in turn it worked for them, but for some reason i keep getting this error and have no idea what to - I am using MVC5 on VS Community :
Could someone help me figure out where I have gone wrong? I do not even know where to begin :(

[image: screenshot1: Movie.cs (my Model)]

[image: Screenshot2: MoviesController.cs (my Controller)[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI1HT.jpg)
[[image]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZHBd.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You have referenced `_ViewStart.cshtml` file and that's not correct. This file and it's name has a special meaning to MVC framework. You cannot specify it, it is picked up internally by framework.

1. If you intend to set a layout file then change the name of that file.
2. If it is really a view start file then remove that Layout property assignment.
3. If you want a better way, open up view start file and set the layout property in it.

**_BasicLayout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>@RenderBody()</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/_BasicLayout.cshtml";
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index view does not need to reference _VewStart.cshtml explicitly";
}
```

Comment: what you recommended worked perfectly. I changed it as you said and the output worked! thank you very much !rather than the BasicLayout i changed it to set the layout property instead, , worked like a charm!

Comment: You are free to give any name to layout file since you can set it explicitly. You can try that. You may also want to mark as answer to help people in future.